# How to create an array of separate strings from a string

Tags: arrays, swift, string

This was tricky to explain in the title, but I have a string like this:

`"One two three four"`

How can I split it so it results in an array like this:

`["four", "three four", "two three four", "one two three four"]`

Comment: It's appreciated if you do some research before posting a question and include what you have attempted instead of just treating stackoverflow like some kind of free code writing service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
let str = "One two three four".components(separatedBy: " ")  
let res = str.indices.map { str[0...$0].joined(separator: " ") } 
print(res)
```

---

```
let str = Array("One two three four".components(separatedBy: " ").reversed())
let res = str.indices.map { str[0...$0].reversed().joined(separator: " ") }
print(res)
```

Comment: This works -- but I made an edit to the question so the output is different - can you check?

Comment: Similarly: `let str = "One two three four".split(separator: " "); let res = str.indices.map { str.suffix($0 + 1).joined(separator: " ") }`

Answer (score 0):

You can split up your `String` into words using `String.components(separatedBy:)` and then `map` over the indices of the `Array` to get its first `n` elements using `prefix(through:)` and `joined(separator:)` to join the individual strings into a single one.

```
let stringWithWords = "One two three four"
let words = stringWithWords.components(separatedBy: " ")
let wordsArray = words.indices.map({words.prefix(through: $0).joined(separator: " ")})
```